# boost::weak_ptr interaction with custom deleter

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I have a `boost::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter attached. When converting this to `weak_ptr` is the deleter information lost? If yes, how do I reattach the same deleter to `shared_ptr`-s  acquired from `weak_ptr::lock()` method?

The feature I am implementing is a container of `weak_ptr`-s pointing to the alive instances of some type. I need the custom deleter to remove the container entry for objects being deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the custom deleter is never lost.

When you `lock()` your `weak_ptr` you regain a `shared_ptr` with the same custom deleter (and other attributes) that the one you use to create the `weak_ptr` from in the first place.

However, If no `shared_ptr` references your `weak_ptr` any longer, the `lock()` will fail and return a null `shared_ptr`.

That is, you shouldn't have to care about the custom deleter. If you specified it upon the `shared_ptr` creation, it will be called when the last related `shared_ptr` will be freed.